# Is it possible to play 1 minute bullet with no increment over the board?

Tags: time-control, illegal-move, bullet-chess

Playing 1 minute bullet games with no increment on the Internet is hard enough, but what about over the board, in real life with an actual wooden board?

Would it be possible, or would 90% of the games end in total chaos with many illegal moves and pieces getting knocked over everywhere?

Would it be possible to have "serious" over the board tournaments played at this time control?

If the answer to the question is no, what about 2 minutes bullet with no increment? Would serious over the board tournaments be possible at this time control?

Comment: God, this question sucks...ever heard of Google?

Answer (score 3):

I've played one minute, no increment, over-the-board chess, it definitely can be done.  My experience (at least with the opponents I've played with...) has been that it's almost always turned into a huge time scramble with lots of knocked-over pieces, and I can tell you that a substantial fraction of the games I've played at this time control (maybe 20% or so - just a guess off the top of my head) have ended with one player or another making an illegal move - often because they didn't notice that they were in check, or because they tried to move a pinned piece or something and ended up putting themselves in check.  Depending on who you are playing with (and your own habits in this regard), I'd personally recommend playing like this only with a clock that you don't really care much about - many of the opponents I've played at this time control have been really rough on the clock...

Answer (score 1):

Well I,myself, have played quite a lot of both 1-minute and 2-minute bullet chess games on a real board. I'd recommend a vinyl board rather than a wooden one, and I have to say it won't end up in total chaos if you have two players who are used to playing 3 minute bullet chess or something alike, so they get used to playing with under a minute on their clocks, and of course who are good enough to be able to think of decent moves with such little time available. (with no increment)

Answer (score -1):

Definitely.  To name one, Grandmaster Ben Finegold was astonishingly good at this from a very young age.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely possible. The current world champion Magnus Carlsen does this all the time and with ease -

[Hans Bohm vs Magnus Carlsen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nYwTWycVSM)

[Magnus Carlsen vs Lars Monsen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1O0xYkYXMu8)